# Is there a covering space from annulus to a mobius strip and vice versa?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I want to know if there is a covering from annulus to a mobius strip? and also whether there is a covering from a mobius strip to annulus? I've done some stuff, but I wanna know if I'm right.

1. I think there is no covering from mobius strip to an annulus. The reason being that: As homeomorphisms carry boundary points of manifolds to boundary points, we can check that covering map between manifolds restricts to a covering map of their boundaries. So, if we consider the mapping from M(Mobius strip) onto B(any other manifold), then the euler characteristic $X(B)$ = $k_X(M)$ = 0. So, B is either a Mobius strip, Klein bottle, , torus or annulus. The torus and Klein bottle are impossible, since they have no boundary, and the annulus is impossible since it has two boundary circles and M has only one. Therefore, there is only a covering from mobius strip onto itself and not any onto annulus. Is the statement and the corresponding reasoning correct?

2. I think there is a covering from annulus to the Mobius strip. I think annulus is a double covering space of the Mobius strip. I know the picture, and as an example I've found is the quotient map of $S^1 \times I \rightarrow S^1 \times I/\sim$ where $(x,t)\sim(x+\pi, 1-t)$,but is the statement correct?